# Finding the median when given a table of score interval and frequency

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There are 20 quiz scores in a typing class, the table below gives the frequency of those scores in each interval. Which s check score interval contains the median of the scores

```
Score interval    Frequency 
96-100                3
91-95                 1
86-90                 3
81-85                 4
76-80                 9
```

I found the solution to be the 81-85 interval because I took the twenty test score and divided by 5 ( the 5 different score intervals) and got the answer... however what is a more logical way of viewing this question, I want to know why what I did works

Answer (score 1):

The median is just the middle score in the sorted data set. Since there are twenty scores, the median will be the average of the tenth and eleventh score in order (since there are an even number of scores in the date set). Since it appears that there are nine scores in the interval 76-80, both the tenth and eleventh score must be in the 81-85 interval, so the median also must be in the 81-85 interval.

It's not exactly clear what you did, but since you say you divided by five, it looks like you were calculating something more like the mean of the data set. You got lucky that your calculation lands in that interval too.